# variable not getting passed between classes? are my for loops structured wrong?

Tags: c++, for-loop, math, output

[image]

I need the following code to look like the output above, however I'm having a hard time getting it like this. For some reason I think that the rate variable isn't ever getting populated and i'm not sure why. Also I'm having a hard time getting the bonus to calculate and show up properly.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Chap1227.h"

using namespace std;

//function prototypes
double getBonusRate(double rate);
void columnsDashes();
void endPgm();


int main() {

    double rate = 0.0;

        //filling array
        int salesArray[10][4] = {{2400, 3500, 2000, 2750},
                                 {1500, 7000, 1000, 2225},
                                 {2600, 2450, 2100, 2999},
                                 {2790, 2240, 2500, 2885},
                                 {2100, 2600, 2300, 3000},
                                 {6300, 7000, 8000, 5550},
                                 {3300, 1850, 2950, 2100},
                                 {2700, 5500, 6000, 7200},
                                 {4700, 4800, 4900, 5100},
                                 {2375, 3300, 2550, 1925}};

        getBonusRate(rate);

        columnsDashes();

        //bonus object
        Bonus myBonus;

        myBonus.calcAndDisplay(salesArray, rate);

        endPgm();


    return 0;
}

// ***** getBonusRate function description *****
//
double getBonusRate(double rate)
{
    //display console title to user
    cout << "JM SALES BONUS CALCULATOR\n\n";

    //get bonus rate from user
    cout << "Enter bonus rate in decimal form: ";
    cin >> rate;
    cout << "\n\n";

    return rate;
}

// ***** columnsDashes function description *****
//
void columnsDashes()
{
    //display column headings and dashes to user
    cout << "Number     Sales($)     Bonus($)\n";
    cout << "------     --------     --------\n";



}

// ***** endPgm function description *****
//
void endPgm()
{
    //EOP message
    cout << "\n\nEnd of Program.";
}
```

Above is the cpp and below is the .h file

```
#ifndef CHAP1227_H_
#define CHAP1227_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

// ***** CLASS DEFINITION *****
class Bonus
{
    public:
       Bonus();
       void calcAndDisplay(int salesArray[10][4], double rate);

    private:
       int totSales;
       int grandTotSales;
       double salesBonus;
       double bonusGrandTot;
};

// ***** CLASS IMPLEMENTATION *****
//default constructor
Bonus::Bonus()
{
    totSales = 0;
    grandTotSales = 0;
    salesBonus = 0.0;
    bonusGrandTot = 0.0;
}

//calcAndDisplay function
//
void Bonus::calcAndDisplay(int salesArray[10][4], double rate)
{

    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row += 1)
        {
            cout << row << "        ";
            for (int column = 0; column < 4; column += 1)
            {
                totSales += salesArray[row][column];

                salesBonus = totSales * rate;
                bonusGrandTot += salesBonus;

            }
            cout << totSales << "\n";
            grandTotSales += totSales;
            totSales = 0;

        }
    cout << setprecision(2);
    cout << salesBonus;
    cout << grandTotSales << " " << bonusGrandTot;
}


#endif /* CHAP1227_H_ */
```

Comment: See pass-by-value, pass-by-reference and how to retrieve return arguments as results of a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem over here is that you are passing the 'rate' variable by "call by value" instead of "call by reference". 
To make it work you just have to redefine your getBonusRate function to following,

```
double getBonusRate(double& rate)
{
    //display console title to user
    cout << "JM SALES BONUS CALCULATOR\n\n";

    //get bonus rate from user
    cout << "Enter bonus rate in decimal form: ";
    cin >> rate;
    cout << "\n\n";

    return rate;
}
```

Remember the '&' symbol it indicates that you are passing your rate variable by refrence.

For more details on call by value and call by reference please check following,

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_value.htm
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, "rate" is not being populated, becasuse you have multiple variables called "rate".  It's like having many people named "Bob"... "Bob Smith", "Bob Jones", "Bob Thompson"

getBonusRate() gets it's own copy of "rate" so it's "getBonusRate::rate" and the main function has it's own copy of "main::rate".  The compiler sees this full name, but your code only sees the short name "rate".

Your function getBonusRate() has an argument type, and a return type.
It's an in door and an out door.  You pass rate in, but it doesn't come out.

To fix, you'd need to say something like:

```
outRate = getBonusRate(inRate);
```

inRate gets copied into the getBonusRate() function, which does it's thing, then it returns it back, and you assign the value to outRate.  You can reuse/overwrite variables, so you can do this, too:
    inRate = getBonusRate(inRate);

Comment: Or you can also do what shobi suggested.  His is probably the more industry-standard approach (slightly faster performance).  Mine is the textbook explanation (it explains return types, and hints at the concept of scope).